# How do I change the arrow in the select with Choices to an inline SVG?

Tags: javascript, select

I can't figure out how I can change the dropdown arrow to an inline SVG with https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices. 
**I know, that I can change it via CSS.**

This is my code as far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Choices Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
            />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js@9.0.1/public/assets/styles/choices.min.css"
            />

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js@9.0.1/public/assets/scripts/choices.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .svg-inline {
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: inherit;
                max-height: 1em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Single select input</h2>
        <label for="choices-single-default">Default</label>
        <select class="form-control" data-trigger name="choices-single-default" id="choices-single-default" placeholder="This is a search placeholder">
            <option value="">This is a placeholder</option>
            <option value="Choice 1">Choice 1</option>
            <option value="Choice 2">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="Choice 3">Choice 3</option>
        </select>
        <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="svg-inline svg-icon__star" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M259.3 17.8L194 150.2 47.9 171.5c-26.2 3.8-36.7 36.1-17.7 54.6l105.7 103-25 145.5c-4.5 26.3 23.2 46 46.4 33.7L288 439.6l130.7 68.7c23.2 12.2 50.9-7.4 46.4-33.7l-25-145.5 105.7-103c19-18.5 8.5-50.8-17.7-54.6L382 150.2 316.7 17.8c-11.7-23.6-45.6-23.9-57.4 0z"></path></svg>                            
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var genericExamples = document.querySelectorAll('[data-trigger]');
                for (i = 0; i < genericExamples.length; ++i) {
                    var element = genericExamples[i];
                    new Choices(element, {
                        placeholderValue: 'This is a placeholder set in the config',
                        searchPlaceholderValue: 'This is a search placeholder',
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I would like to put the star in the place of the arrow.

[image]

Comment: Instead of inserting an inline SVG image, you are probably better off using the SVG image as the background. If you inpsect the markup of the custom select element being rendered, the arrow is being styled as a pseudo-element on the seletor `.choices[data-type*=select-one]:after`.

Comment: Thanks, I know that I could do it with CSS and Background-Image. Bug I like to do it with an inline. Perhaps there is a way I do not see at the Moment.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement it, making changes to the css, only if you need to put an SVG as such you have to get the code, I will show you how to do your approach but with the fontawesome icons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Choices Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
            />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js@9.0.1/public/assets/styles/choices.min.css"
            />

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js@9.0.1/public/assets/scripts/choices.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
   <style>
    .choices[data-type*="select-one"]::after {
        content: "\f005";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #333 transparent transparent;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: none;
        border-color: inherit;
        border-width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 24.5px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -10.5px;
        pointer-events: none;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Single select input</h2>
        <label for="choices-single-default">Default</label>
        <select class="form-control" data-trigger name="choices-single-default" id="choices-single-default" placeholder="This is a search placeholder">
            <option value="">This is a placeholder</option>
            <option value="Choice 1">Choice 1</option>
            <option value="Choice 2">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="Choice 3">Choice 3</option>
        </select>
                                   
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var genericExamples = document.querySelectorAll('[data-trigger]');
                for (i = 0; i < genericExamples.length; ++i) {
                    var element = genericExamples[i];
                    new Choices(element, {
                        placeholderValue: 'This is a placeholder set in the config',
                        searchPlaceholderValue: 'This is a search placeholder',
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```